# Constraints animation is incorrect

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, nslayoutconstraint

I created uiview custom class and implemented in Main View Controller

```
-(KPHomeChartCategory *)chartCategory {

    if (!_chartCategory) {
    _chartCategory = [[KPHomeChartCategory alloc] init];
    _chartCategory.delegate = self;
    _chartCategory.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self addSubview:_chartCategory];

    [self.chartCategory.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.topAnchor constant:-7.5].active = YES;
    [self.chartCategory.rightAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.rightAnchor].active = YES;

    self.chartCategoryLeftAnchor = [self.chartCategory.leftAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.rightAnchor];
    self.chartCategoryLeftAnchor.active = YES;

    [self.chartCategory.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:100].active = YES;

    }
    return _chartCategory;
}
```

I animated uiview custom class **(KPHomeChartCategory)** constraints in this way

```
-(void)openPanelTagAnimation {

    self.chartCategoryLeftAnchor.active = NO;
    self.chartCategoryLeftAnchor = [self.chartCategory.leftAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.rightAnchor constant:-self.frame.size.width +105];
    self.chartCategoryLeftAnchor.active = YES;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:.6 delay:0 usingSpringWithDamping:1 initialSpringVelocity:1 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
        self.customSwitch.alpha = 0;
        [self layoutIfNeeded];
    } completion:nil];
}
```

Now if you look at the video, you will notice that the first time I show customView, my collection view is shown from above but afterwards the animation seems to be perfectly straightforward ... can you make me understand why this thing?

**Video Link**
  [VIDEO ANIMATION](https://streamable.com/zeaep)

Why my animation first starts from top to bottom and only then is linear ? (the linear animation from right to left is the correct one and should be the first time the custom view is animated)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the animation you posted the cells are animating because their initial size is `CGSizeZero` or some value close to that and then the collection view layout invalidates so their size is increased. You could avoid this by animating the `transform` property of your collection view. This will like solve the problem you mention [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46935860/5442445) as well. For example in a simple demo, I can place a collection view by pinning top, left and right to its superview with a constant height. I set the cell sizes programmatically like:

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return CGSizeMake(collectionView.bounds.size.width / 3.0, collectionView.bounds.size.height);
}
```

Then I use a `CGAffineTransform` to move the collection view off screen. For example:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    self.collectionView.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(CGAffineTransformIdentity, self.view.bounds.size.width, 0.0);
}
```

Finally, when I want to perform an animation, I set the transform back to its identity:

```
- (void)animate {
    // Reversing and repeating for the sake of testing
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse animations:^{
        self.collectionView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    } completion:nil];
}
```

Using this method ensures that cells are always the same size and thus won't animate when constraints change in an animation block.

When I change constraints in my demo project this is the animation, notice the cell sizes change on the initial animation.

[image]

The same animation when setting `transform`:

[image]

Comment: beyowulf hello ... i have implemented your method correctly and now it works perfectly .. i want to thank you for your help ... i have an animation with a boolean value tagPanelIsOpen: (BOOL) open ... i wanted to ask you if CGAffineTransformIdentity i need enter it when the value is YES and when the value is NO? or only when the value is YES?

Comment: Think you want it to be `CGAffineTransformIdentity` when the panel should be completely onscreen and and equal to the translation when you want to to be offscreen.

Comment: Well... then before show ( before constraint Change) and before hide ... right?

Comment: Beyowulf When my collectionView is completely open, a UILabel appears on its left that should show the contents of the uilabel cell custom. As soon as I select a cell the uicollectionView disappears ... Why? if I remove collectionView.transform from the LayoutSubview method (so my animation does not work) then the collectionView does not disappear when I select a cell ... How can I fix it? why does this happen?

Comment: Is there a way I can see all of your code? In a repo or in a gist maybe?